# \n problem when using javascript to exec "python -c "

Tags: javascript, python

```
function get_params(command_string,tpp){
    var rt = "None"
    // 如果存在->那么取出值并覆盖
    if(command_string.search("->") != -1){
        rt = /->(.*):/.exec(command_string)[1]
        var rep = /\)(\s{0,1}->\s{0,1}.*):/.exec(command_string)[1];
        command_string = command_string.replace(rep, "");
    }
    command_string = command_string.replace(/(^\s*)/g, "");


    var func_name = /^def ([_\da-zA-Z]+)\(.*/.exec(command_string)[1]

    var comon = `python -c "
import inspect
import json
from typing import *
from datetime import *
result = []
${command_string}
    pass
for x in inspect.signature(${func_name}).parameters.values():
    try:
        result.append(dict(name=x.name, annotation=x.annotation.__name__ if x.annotation != inspect._empty else 'Undeclared', default= x.default if x.default != inspect._empty else 'Undeclared')) 
    except Exception:
        result.append(dict(name=x.name, annotation=x.annotation._name if x.annotation != inspect._empty else 'Undeclared', default= x.default if x.default != inspect._empty else 'Undeclared'))
print(json.dumps(result))
"`
    console.log(comon)
    var message = execute(comon).toString();
    return {
        "params":GenarateParamDoc(JSON.parse(message), tpp),
        "rt": rt
}
}
```

I try to use javascript to execute some python code by "python -c". it works in Linux, 
but I don't know why failed in windows and mac,
I guess it caused by the difference between \n \r\n  and \r.

so I want to ask how to fix this problem.

this project is in https://github.com/QUANTAXIS/QAHelper

you can clone it and run in vscode.

Comment: don't you get any error message ? Maybe there is more information.

Comment: in javascript i don't get any useful message