# how to use python -c on windows?

Tags: python

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

This is the option documentation. but it doesn't provide me any useful message

I want to execute code in this way

```
python -c "def hello():\n    print('hello world')"
```

the error message

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> python -c "def hello():\n    print('hello world')"
  File "<string>", line 1
    def hello():\n    print('hello world')
                                         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

it works on Linux, but not windows.

Hope you can give a  full fixed command ~~~

Another question connected with this one 
[\n problem when using javascript to exec "python -c "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407516/n-problem-when-using-javascript-to-exec-python-c)

Comment: What means does not work on Windows? Any error Message? If so pls add it in an edit.

Comment: What would be the point of running this command? It defines a function that is never executed.

Comment: @khelwood I find it an interesting question if posed as "how can I define and call a function using `python -c` in windows?" [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#interface-options) make it sound like it should work

Comment: I just want to execute code in this way.

Comment: @somewheve the easy way would be to create a file and execute that - or avoid defining functions or classes, and chain commands using `;`

Comment: I have updated question, now you can see it on the question

Comment: @lucidbrot I can't use file, I want to create a fast-generate tool in vscode. help to write annotations fast.  `;` not work.  you can see  this project on   https://github.com/QUANTAXIS/QAHelper

Comment: @lucidbrot I guess the error caused by the "\n". in  Linux, it works.  but not mac and windows.

Comment: I have to "\n" to execute much code and parse  the annotations by inspect module. Hope you can help me.  I hate "\n" on windows. what a bad design !!!

Comment: @HeapOverflow  all code is not just like only two lines.  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nc8VmRSrKS/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try backtick instead of backslash.

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\me> python -c "def hello():\n    print('hello world')"
  File "<string>", line 1
    def hello():\n    print('hello world')
                                         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
PS C:\Users\me>
```

Ok:

```
PS C:\Users\me> python -c "def hello():`n    print('hello world')"
PS C:\Users\me>
```

Useful:

```
PS C:\Users\me> python -c "def hello():`n    print('hello world')`nhello()"
hello world
PS C:\Users\me>
```

Just echoing to see it:

```
PS C:\Users\me> echo "def hello():`n    print('hello world')`nhello()"
def hello():
    print('hello world')
hello()
PS C:\Users\me>
```

See [PowerTip: New Lines with PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-new-lines-with-powershell/)

Comment: Hey ,  I try to call command  `powershell -Command "python -c 'import inspect\`nimport datetime' " `  in  cmd , but it is not accept by the cmd.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are perhaps expecting `\n` to be translated to a newline by something ... be that the shell (`cmd.exe` presumably), or python itself.

Neither is doing so.  Instead, if your shell is `cmd.exe` then you should use a line continuation character and enter an **actual** newline.

For example, suppose you wished to effectively `echo` the words *blob* and *blub* with a new line.  Then you would use:

```
c:\>echo blob^
More? <press enter>
More? blub
blob
blub
```

So ... equivalently

```
c:\>python -c "def hello():"^
More?
More? "  print('hello world')"^
<no output, all you did was define a function>
```

To call it then

```
c:\>python -c "def hello():"^
More? <press return>
More? "  print('hello world')"^
More? <press return>
More> hello()
hello world
```

Comment: but how can I use code to create this input.....  in fact I use execSync to execute this command by javascript

Comment: can you give me your full command ?   not understand what you mean...

Comment: @somewheve ... if you are using `execSync`, then **why are you not using the `input` parameter to stream the code on `stdin` instead of using `-c`**?

Comment: at that time, I think it's an easy way to do this.. so I choose it. and successful on Linux

Comment: but the windows makes me sad.